# Is it possible on IBM i to setup a *SYSTEM Certificate Store in the Digital Certifcate Manager with an API?

Tags: http, ssl, websphere, ibm-midrange

Is it possible on IBM i to setup a *SYSTEM Certificate Store in the Digital Certifcate Manager withan API from IBM i?
I'm looking for a solution where I can execute the steps in this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaiq/rzaiqcrtsystctfct.htm) with an API, but I couldn't find something helpful.

Here's an overview for Digitial Certificate Manager [APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/secex1.htm) and SSL [APIS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/unix9.htm).

I'm using IBM i V7.2.

Maybe someone already integrated something like this in a service program?
Also the use of Scott Klement's HTTPLIB would be acceptable.

Thanks!